# prevent tables to move when zooming - CSS

Tags: html, css, css-tables

.
Hi guys, when I zoom out, the last tables move to the next row. Is there a way to fix the layout so that the tables don't move to the next row? Could you please give me some advice or a workaround so that I can fix this problem?
I have tried many things but unfortunately I cannot find the solution. Thanks in advance for all your support and comments.

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
}

.first,
.second {
  width: 50px;
}

.third {
  text-align: right;
}

#customers {
  font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: auto;
}

.blocks {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}

#customers td,
#customers th {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  font-size: 11px;
  width: auto;
  padding: 1px;
}

#customers tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
}

#customers tr:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.vork {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: right;
  width: 2.5em;
}
```

```html
<div class="blocks">
  <div class="block">
    <table class="table-responsive" id="customers" colspan="7" style="float: left; margin-left: 15px;">
      <tr>
        <td width="100" style="font-weight: bold; font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color:#FFFFFF; background-color:#000000; font-size:11px; 1px solid #000000;">Status</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td width="100"><span class="vork">1:</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="nachkomma">Testtask 25362541</span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td width="100"><span class="vork">2:</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="nachkomma">Testtask 6545645641</span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td width="100"><span class="vork">53:</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="nachkomma">Testtask 4846465463</span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td width="100"><span class="vork">4:</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="nachkomma">Testtask 4846465464</span></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div class="block">
    <table class="table-responsive" id="customers" colspan="7" style="float: left; margin-left: 15px;">
      <tr>
        <td width="100" style="font-weight: bold; font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color:#FFFFFF; background-color:#000000; font-size:11px; 1px solid #000000;">Status</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td width="100"><span class="vork">1:</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="nachkomma">Testtask 25362541</span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td width="100"><span class="vork">2:</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="nachkomma">Testtask 6545645641</span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td width="100"><span class="vork">53:</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="nachkomma">Testtask 4846465463</span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td width="100"><span class="vork">4:</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="nachkomma">Testtask 4846465464</span></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div class="block">
    <table class="table-responsive" id="customers" colspan="7" style="float: left; margin-left: 15px;">
      <tr>
        <td width="100" style="font-weight: bold; font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color:#FFFFFF; background-color:#000000; font-size:11px; 1px solid #000000;">Status</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td width="100"><span class="vork">1:</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="nachkomma">Testtask 25362541</span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td width="100"><span class="vork">2:</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="nachkomma">Testtask 6545645641</span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td width="100"><span class="vork">53:</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="nachkomma">Testtask 4846465463</span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td width="100"><span class="vork">4:</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="nachkomma">Testtask 4846465464</span></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div class="block">
    <table class="table-responsive" id="customers" colspan="7" style="float: left; margin-left: 15px;">
      <tr>
        <td width="100" style="font-weight: bold; font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color:#FFFFFF; background-color:#000000; font-size:11px; 1px solid #000000;">Status</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td width="100"><span class="vork">1:</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="nachkomma">Testtask 25362541</span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td width="100"><span class="vork">2:</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="nachkomma">Testtask 6545645641</span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td width="100"><span class="vork">53:</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="nachkomma">Testtask 4846465463</span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td width="100"><span class="vork">4:</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="nachkomma">Testtask 4846465464</span></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div class="block">
    <table class="table-responsive" id="customers" colspan="7" style="float: left; margin-left: 15px;">
      <tr>
        <td width="100" style="font-weight: bold; font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color:#FFFFFF; background-color:#000000; font-size:11px; 1px solid #000000;">Status</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td width="100"><span class="vork">1:</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="nachkomma">Testtask 25362541</span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td width="100"><span class="vork">2:</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="nachkomma">Testtask 6545645641</span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td width="100"><span class="vork">53:</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="nachkomma">Testtask 4846465463</span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>

        <td width="100"><span class="vork">4:</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="nachkomma">Testtask 4846465464</span></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div class="block">
    <table class="table-responsive" id="customers" colspan="7" style="float: left; margin-left: 15px;">
      <tr>
        <td width="100" style="font-weight: bold; font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color:#FFFFFF; background-color:#000000; font-size:11px; 1px solid #000000;">Status</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td width="100"><span class="vork">1:</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="nachkomma">Testtask 25362541</span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td width="100"><span class="vork">2:</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="nachkomma">Testtask 6545645641</span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td width="100"><span class="vork">53:</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="nachkomma">Testtask 4846465463</span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td width="100"><span class="vork">4:</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="nachkomma">Testtask 4846465464</span></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

set `display` of `.blocks` to `flex` to keep all tables keep in a row.

Comment: @James you may need to set other styles with `flex` to achieve what you want. For example, use a `min-width` to avoid the table get too narrow.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, browsers scale tables differently than other content at very small sizes. So you need a solution that will force three items per row. There are a few ways to handle this in CSS.

The first uses [CSS Grid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout). See the changes to `.blocks` below. Note that IE11 has limited grid support, so you may need to add additional CSS to get it working in that browser.

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
}

.first,
.second {
  width: 50px;
}

.third {
  text-align: right;
}

#customers {
  font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: auto;
}

.blocks {
  display: inline-grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 1fr);
  position: relative;
}

#customers td,
#customers th {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  font-size: 11px;
  width: auto;
  padding: 1px;
}

#customers tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
}

#customers tr:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.vork {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: right;
  width: 2.5em;
}
```

```html
<div class="blocks">
  <div class="block">
    <table class="table-responsive" id="customers" colspan="7" style="float: left; margin-left: 15px;">
      <tr>
        <td width="100" style="font-weight: bold; font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color:#FFFFFF; background-color:#000000; font-size:11px; 1px solid #000000;">Status</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td width="100"><span class="vork">1:</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="nachkomma">Testtask 25362541</span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td width="100"><span class="vork">2:</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="nachkomma">Testtask 6545645641</span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td width="100"><span class="vork">53:</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="nachkomma">Testtask 4846465463</span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td width="100"><span class="vork">4:</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="nachkomma">Testtask 4846465464</span></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div class="block">
    <table class="table-responsive" id="customers" colspan="7" style="float: left; margin-left: 15px;">
      <tr>
        <td width="100" style="font-weight: bold; font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color:#FFFFFF; background-color:#000000; font-size:11px; 1px solid #000000;">Status</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td width="100"><span class="vork">1:</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="nachkomma">Testtask 25362541</span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td width="100"><span class="vork">2:</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="nachkomma">Testtask 6545645641</span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td width="100"><span class="vork">53:</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="nachkomma">Testtask 4846465463</span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td width="100"><span class="vork">4:</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="nachkomma">Testtask 4846465464</span></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div class="block">
    <table class="table-responsive" id="customers" colspan="7" style="float: left; margin-left: 15px;">
      <tr>
        <td width="100" style="font-weight: bold; font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color:#FFFFFF; background-color:#000000; font-size:11px; 1px solid #000000;">Status</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td width="100"><span class="vork">1:</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="nachkomma">Testtask 25362541</span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td width="100"><span class="vork">2:</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="nachkomma">Testtask 6545645641</span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td width="100"><span class="vork">53:</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="nachkomma">Testtask 4846465463</span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td width="100"><span class="vork">4:</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="nachkomma">Testtask 4846465464</span></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div class="block">
    <table class="table-responsive" id="customers" colspan="7" style="float: left; margin-left: 15px;">
      <tr>
        <td width="100" style="font-weight: bold; font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color:#FFFFFF; background-color:#000000; font-size:11px; 1px solid #000000;">Status</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td width="100"><span class="vork">1:</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="nachkomma">Testtask 25362541</span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td width="100"><span class="vork">2:</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="nachkomma">Testtask 6545645641</span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td width="100"><span class="vork">53:</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="nachkomma">Testtask 4846465463</span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td width="100"><span class="vork">4:</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="nachkomma">Testtask 4846465464</span></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div class="block">
    <table class="table-responsive" id="customers" colspan="7" style="float: left; margin-left: 15px;">
      <tr>
        <td width="100" style="font-weight: bold; font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color:#FFFFFF; background-color:#000000; font-size:11px; 1px solid #000000;">Status</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td width="100"><span class="vork">1:</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="nachkomma">Testtask 25362541</span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td width="100"><span class="vork">2:</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="nachkomma">Testtask 6545645641</span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td width="100"><span class="vork">53:</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="nachkomma">Testtask 4846465463</span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>

        <td width="100"><span class="vork">4:</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="nachkomma">Testtask 4846465464</span></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div class="block">
    <table class="table-responsive" id="customers" colspan="7" style="float: left; margin-left: 15px;">
      <tr>
        <td width="100" style="font-weight: bold; font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color:#FFFFFF; background-color:#000000; font-size:11px; 1px solid #000000;">Status</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td width="100"><span class="vork">1:</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="nachkomma">Testtask 25362541</span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td width="100"><span class="vork">2:</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="nachkomma">Testtask 6545645641</span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td width="100"><span class="vork">53:</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="nachkomma">Testtask 4846465463</span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td width="100"><span class="vork">4:</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="nachkomma">Testtask 4846465464</span></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Another solution that will work in all browsers (and probably get me some hate mail) is to use nested tables.

```css
.first,
.second {
  width: 50px;
}

.third {
  text-align: right;
}

#customers {
  font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: auto;
}

#customers td,
#customers th {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  font-size: 11px;
  width: auto;
  padding: 1px;
}

#customers tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
}

#customers tr:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.vork {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: right;
  width: 2.5em;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <table class="table-responsive" id="customers" colspan="7" style="float: left; margin-left: 15px;">
        <tr>
          <td width="100" style="font-weight: bold; font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color:#FFFFFF; background-color:#000000; font-size:11px; 1px solid #000000;">Status</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td width="100"><span class="vork">1:</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="nachkomma">Testtask 25362541</span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td width="100"><span class="vork">2:</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="nachkomma">Testtask 6545645641</span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td width="100"><span class="vork">53:</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="nachkomma">Testtask 4846465463</span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td width="100"><span class="vork">4:</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="nachkomma">Testtask 4846465464</span></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
    <td>
      <table class="table-responsive" id="customers" colspan="7" style="float: left; margin-left: 15px;">
        <tr>
          <td width="100" style="font-weight: bold; font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color:#FFFFFF; background-color:#000000; font-size:11px; 1px solid #000000;">Status</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td width="100"><span class="vork">1:</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="nachkomma">Testtask 25362541</span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td width="100"><span class="vork">2:</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="nachkomma">Testtask 6545645641</span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td width="100"><span class="vork">53:</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="nachkomma">Testtask 4846465463</span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td width="100"><span class="vork">4:</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="nachkomma">Testtask 4846465464</span></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
    <td>
      <table class="table-responsive" id="customers" colspan="7" style="float: left; margin-left: 15px;">
        <tr>
          <td width="100" style="font-weight: bold; font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color:#FFFFFF; background-color:#000000; font-size:11px; 1px solid #000000;">Status</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td width="100"><span class="vork">1:</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="nachkomma">Testtask 25362541</span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td width="100"><span class="vork">2:</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="nachkomma">Testtask 6545645641</span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td width="100"><span class="vork">53:</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="nachkomma">Testtask 4846465463</span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td width="100"><span class="vork">4:</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="nachkomma">Testtask 4846465464</span></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
    <td>
      <table class="table-responsive" id="customers" colspan="7" style="float: left; margin-left: 15px;">
        <tr>
          <td width="100" style="font-weight: bold; font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color:#FFFFFF; background-color:#000000; font-size:11px; 1px solid #000000;">Status</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td width="100"><span class="vork">1:</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="nachkomma">Testtask 25362541</span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td width="100"><span class="vork">2:</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="nachkomma">Testtask 6545645641</span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td width="100"><span class="vork">53:</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="nachkomma">Testtask 4846465463</span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td width="100"><span class="vork">4:</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="nachkomma">Testtask 4846465464</span></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
    <td>
      <table class="table-responsive" id="customers" colspan="7" style="float: left; margin-left: 15px;">
        <tr>
          <td width="100" style="font-weight: bold; font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color:#FFFFFF; background-color:#000000; font-size:11px; 1px solid #000000;">Status</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td width="100"><span class="vork">1:</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="nachkomma">Testtask 25362541</span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td width="100"><span class="vork">2:</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="nachkomma">Testtask 6545645641</span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td width="100"><span class="vork">53:</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="nachkomma">Testtask 4846465463</span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>

          <td width="100"><span class="vork">4:</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="nachkomma">Testtask 4846465464</span></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
    <td>
      <table class="table-responsive" id="customers" colspan="7" style="float: left; margin-left: 15px;">
        <tr>
          <td width="100" style="font-weight: bold; font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color:#FFFFFF; background-color:#000000; font-size:11px; 1px solid #000000;">Status</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td width="100"><span class="vork">1:</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="nachkomma">Testtask 25362541</span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td width="100"><span class="vork">2:</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="nachkomma">Testtask 6545645641</span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td width="100"><span class="vork">53:</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="nachkomma">Testtask 4846465463</span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td width="100"><span class="vork">4:</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="nachkomma">Testtask 4846465464</span></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: thank you for the support! i have to display and keep all tables in a row when zooming out. do you have another advices?

Comment: The easiest way to get all six tables displaying in a single row is to follow @GellioGao's advice and use flexbox. That said, I've updated both my examples to show a single row instead of two.